# Pandas method chaining when df not assigned yet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to do method chaining in pandas when

- no variable refering to the dataframe has been assigned, yet
- AND the method needs to refer to the dataframe?

**Example**: here data frame can be referred to by variable name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":list("abc")})
df = (df
      .drop(df.tail(1).index)
      #.other_methods
      #...
      )
df
```

Is it possible to do this without having assigned the dataframe to a variable name?

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":list("abc")})
      .drop(??.tail(1).index)
      #.other_methods
      #...
      )
df
```

Thanks!

Comment: Then you'll have to write the df definition `pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":list("abc")})` everywhere.

Comment: use a lambda function

Comment: This does come up in a few other contexts, i.e. you do some groupby, then want to do some calculation where you reference the groupby output, but can't because it _doesnt'_ exist. I don't think there's _any_ runtime improvements for chained methods vs just splitting them out. Maybe there's some memory benefits, but again you're just overwriting in the end so my guess is they're fairly similar by the end of the methods. Sometimes `eval` can be used, or `query`, but other times for more complex manipulations you can't really

Comment: @MayankPorwal That doesn't work if any of the methods mutate the dataframe, because you'll be working with multiple individual data frames rather than using the same one everywhere.

Comment: @chepner Makes sense. Got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some reference to the dataframe in order to use it in multiple independent places. That means binding a reusable name to the value returned by `pd.DataFrame`.

A "functional" way to create such a binding is to use a lambda expression instead of an assignment statement.

```
df = (lambda df: df.drop(df.tail(1).index)....)(pd.DataFrame(...))
```

The lambda expression defines some function that uses whatever value is passed as an argument as the value of the name `df`; you then immediately call that function on your original dataframe.

Comment: Ah, I tried it with a lambda approach, but did not manage to do this. Thanks! Not that I will use this in practice, but it helped me to understand it better.

Comment: I use it all the time ;) sometimes this is really needed as using intermediate variables would be a pain

Comment: In my case it is only one additional line of code with no big runtime difference (i suppose...). I was just curious if I could get rid of this one line...

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` not `pd.Dataframe`

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to @chepner's answer, note that some methods/indexer support passing a function/lambda natively:

Example with `assign` and `loc`:

```
(pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "B":list("abc")})
 .assign(C=lambda d: d['A']*2)
 .loc[lambda d: d['B'] == 'a']
)
```

output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  a  2
```